# Upstart - setuid inside post-start stanza

Tags: upstart

I have this **upstart** script that looks a bit like this:

```
setuid userA
setgid userB

script
    # ... bunch of stuff run as userA
end script

post-start script
    # ... command run as userA

    # ... the following command needs to be run as root
    setuid root                  # <---- this is not legal syntax
    service myservice restart    # <---- I need to run this as root
end script
```

So, I've gone through the documentation and found out that setuid doesn't work inside `post-start`, and `userA` is not in the sudoer list, so I can't just do `sudo service myservice restart`. In fact, in the most ideal situation, I should actually be running `myservice` as another user instead.

How do I get about this? I'm scratching my head without any solutions for a whole day now.

---

As suggested by the answer, a way is to create *another* upstart job that runs when the previous upstart script runs. So instead of having `service myservice restart` in jobA, we create `/etc/init/myservice-hook.conf` and have it trigger when jobA is running (as per the answer).

On my side, I managed to solve the problem by removing both `setuid` and `setgid` so that the script runs as root, and then selectively putting `sudo -u userA <command>` inside the script. I'll use the answer provided instead because I think it has better isolation of concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create another job like so:

```
start on started jobA

task

exec service myservice restart
```

Then remove the setuid root bit and what was below it in the post-start script.

Comment: That... actually is a fairly elegant solution. I didn't know it could be done in this way.